# Insert in front of string separed by even line breaks something and something else in front of string separed by odd line breaksin excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried for some time to find a solution to put a text in front of a string, like a dialogue, for even and odd line breaks:

this is the string:

```
(What are you doing?
I'm doing well
Tonight what are you doing?
Tonight I'm going to sleep!)
```

to show something like that:

```
person 1: ”What are you doing?”
person 2: ”I'm doing well”
person 1: ”Tonight what are you doing?”
person 2: ”Tonight I'm going to sleep!”
person 1: ”...”
person 2: ”...”
and so on...
```

can somebody help me please?

Comment: `= "Person " & (1+MOD(ROW(),2)) & ":" & ...`

Comment: for example i want to write something in a textbox that then automatically appears in the dialog form, the first line to have the "person 1:" in front, and the second line the "person 2:" in front and the lines of the strings appear in quotes. thank you very much in advance